# Sequence expansion question

Tags: r, sequences

I have a sequence of 'endpoints', e.g.:

```
c(7,10,5,11,15)
```

that I want to expand to a sequence of 'elapsed time' between the endpoints, e.g.

c(**7**,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,**10**,1,2,3,4,**5**,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,**11**,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,**15**)

Whats the most efficient way to do this in R?  I'm imagining some creative use of the `embed` function, but I can't quite get there without using a ugly `for` loop.

Here's the naive way to do this:

```
expandSequence <- function(x) {
    out <- x[1]
    for (y in (x[-1])) {
        out <- c(out,seq(1,y))
    }
    return(out)
}

expandSequence(c(7,10,5,11,15))
```

Comment: Thanks for a nicely worded and reproducible question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a base function to do this, called, wait for it, `sequence`:

```
sequence(c(7,10,5,11,15))

 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3
[26]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

In your case it seems your first endpoint is in fact not part of the sequence, so it becomes:

```
c(7, sequence(c(10,5,11,15)))
 [1]  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[26] 10 11  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch. It is implemented effectively as @gsk and I reinvented. I'd come across `sequence` before but presumed it was an alias for `seq`. Great to find out about these less well-used functions!

Comment: @Andrie: Thanks!  For my next trick, I will reverse engineer the `embed` function.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
> unlist(sapply(x,seq))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  1  2
[25]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

With the first element added on at the end:

```
c( x[1], unlist( sapply( x[seq(2,length(x))], seq ) ) )
```

And a slightly more readable version:

```
library(taRifx)
c( x[1], unlist( sapply( shift(x,wrap=FALSE), seq ) ) )
```

Comment: Sadly my solution doesn't involve bolded numbers. ;-)

Comment: Perfect!  I just got to `do.call(c,mapply(seq,1,x))` but your solution is better.

Comment: Except that isn't the output shown in the Q. The first element should be `7` according to the Q. You have `1:7`.

Comment: So to be complete about this you'd need to omit the first element of `x` from the `sapply` call and then add it back on to the front afterwards, to get the OP's desired output, right?

Comment: If that *is* what the OP wants. He has commented here that the output is "perfect", so perhaps the Q is not exactly what was wanted?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson I added the "omit first element of x and add it back at the end" myself

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `lapply()` and `seq_len()` is useful here:

```
expandSequence <- function(x) {
    out <- lapply(x[-1], seq_len)
    do.call(c, c(x[1], out))
}
```

Which gives for

```
pts <- c(7,10,5,11,15)

> expandSequence(pts)
 [1]  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4
[21]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
[41] 14 15
```

(An alternative is:

```
expandSequence <- function(x) {
    out <- lapply(x[-1], seq_len)
    unlist(c(x[1], out), use.names = FALSE)
}
```

)

Comment: I like reinventing the wheel!